# Pooling Profile Errors in Mule FTP 1.4.1 Connector

Tags: configuration, ftp, connector, mulesoft

I'm using an FTP connector to read a CSV file.  The application is an example app out of Exchange at `ftp.devrel.mulesoft.com`.

It all works fine when the "Pooling profile" in the FTP Config is set to "use default connection pool configuration". Test Connection returns successfully.

If I change the "Pool profile" to Edit inline, and keep all default settings, the connection test fails with the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FTP_Config': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3393fd09' of type [org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.config.dsl.connection.ConnectionProviderObjectFactory$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fc09cb67] while setting bean property 'connectionProviderResolver'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3393fd09': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#52e62e2e' of type [org.mule.runtime.api.config.PoolingProfile] while setting bean property 'poolingProfile'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#52e62e2e': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3: Could not convert argument value of type [null] to required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'null'

      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FTP_Config': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3393fd09' of type [org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.config.dsl.connection.ConnectionProviderObjectFactory$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fc09cb67] while setting bean property 'connectionProviderResolver'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3393fd09': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#52e62e2e' of type [org.mule.runtime.api.config.PoolingProfile] while setting bean property 'poolingProfile'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#52e62e2e': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3: Could not convert argument value of type [null] to required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'null'
        at
```

Comment: Hi, it seems to be a bug related to the test connection features. I can reproduce it. Does it work when you execute the application?

Comment: it works in default config mode.

Comment: My question was if it works when you execute the application as opposed to the Studio connectivity button.